# Website is working perfectly fine on localhost but in production environment showing Content Security Policy error

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy

error displayed on the console:

> 199483d564c61b347c.js:formatted:11 Refused to apply inline style
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-mc5MFFuny++HbPmYE2clhmGeDbhhMCQG815PTPVKnzs='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

***Landing component***

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Landing extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="para1"></div>
                <div className="section white">
                    <div className="row container">
                    <h2 className="header">Goonj</h2>
                    <p className="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Coonect with ngo's</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="para2"></div>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Landing;
```

***landing.css***

```
.para1 {
    background-image: url(../images/goonj1.jpg);
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}

.para2 {
    background-image: url(../images/goonj2.jpg);
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

What should i do to solve it without violating content security policy???

Comment: How are your bundling your code?

Comment: i am using create-react-app and it uses webpack for doing so

Comment: It looks weird to me that this could cause any problem? Are you sure there's nothing else you're not including? What are the row and container classes ?

Comment: Have you read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP?

Comment: i am using materialize css also that's why there are row and container classes and all the errors were of images and it is the only place i have used them

Comment: Gohan67 if you know can you please tell me how to remove it then, without risking security??

Comment: CSP headers can also be set at the server level. Double check that your production server isn’t sending a CSP header that’s missing from Dev server